# Design Questions for a Nixie Tube Clock

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, microchip, nixie

I'm making a Nixie Tube Clock as a project for a class. The whole point of the project is to essentially to do it from scratch. I'll be designing a PCB for the project and I want to put the microcontroller chip directly on the PCB instead of simply using a standalone microcontroller. I've never done this before so I'm just looking for some advice for what is easy to use. Not just from the programming language but also how do I get the program onto the board, connect I/O, and make sure the chip doesn't lose the program every time I disconnect power.

I've programmed in MIPS assembly, C, and C++ before so any chip using those or something similar would be fine for me.

I was thinking about a Atmega328P with the Arduino bootloader already on the chip but that may be overkill for my project.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Vague as all get-out. Perhaps you could do some research yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was thinking about a Atmega328P with the Arduino bootloader already on the chip but that may be overkill for my project.

An ATmega328P is a good choice, as there is a free software toolchain as well as the Arduino IDE if you are more comfortable with that, and programmers are cheap (~$15). Additionally, there is a lot of community support and it is very easy to get an ATmega up and running on a board by itself. Take a look at the Arduino UNO schematic, and strip out the things you don't need. Basically, at a bare minimum, it boils down to the following:

- A stable logic voltage supply (5V or 3V3 would be a good choice).
- A way to program the device. Easiest way to do this is with an ICSP header (6 pins, programmers are cheap, very easy to use).

A crystal is optional. The ATmega328 has an internal oscillator. Because you don't need a high clock frequency, and I presume you'll be using an external RTC, you don't need a stable or fast clock.

You'll need to choose the peripherals for your clock: I'm guessing you'll want an RTC and some I/O expanders (or shift registers) to drive the clock.

---

> make sure the chip doesn't lose the program every time I disconnect power.

Every microcontroller (within reason) has non-volatile (flash-based) program storage and will retain its program code through power cycles.

---

Other reasonable microcontroller alternatives:

- If you need *less* horsepower, an ATtiny would be a reasonable choice. However, most ATtiny's will also have less I/O, which might be an issue. The toolchain/programmer is the same though.
- If you want a more modern/capable/fast MCU, look at ARM Cortex M0+ and M4 chips. I would recommend STMicro or perhaps Freescale (now NXP) Kinetis chips. Keep in mind that STMicro programmers are much cheaper than Freescale programmers.

Comment: If I were to use a battery pack for power would that be stable enough as a logic voltage supply or would I need to do something to clean up the signal before sending it to the Atmega328P?

                                                                                            
I wasn't planning on using an RTC to set the time of the clock. I was going to set up a series of switches and flip them to create the binary representation of the time I'm trying to set and then flip another switch for the clock to recognize the input. I have to have some way a user can input as part of the project.

Comment: How long are you wanting this clock to run? Nixie tubes and batteries are not a usual mix. Without an RTC, it isn't going to be much of a clock i.e. it won't keep time. It's possible to power an ATmega directly from a battery, but you'll need to design for a significant voltage droop over the lifetime of the battery (no ADC, no communication with anything that requires a stable voltage).

Comment: Would using a crystal be worth adding in? Sorry the comments are hard to read I tried to add a blank line between the two questions but whenever I saved it was gone.

Comment: I can scrap the battery idea if it seems unreasonable. That was strictly for aesthetic so I didn't have a cord running from the clock.

Comment: The ATmega328 has an internal 8MHz oscillator. Unless you need the extra cycles (which you don't, in a clock), why bother?

Comment: You'll have to calculate how much current your Nixie tubes require and then calculate battery life from that and see if it's tolerable.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to look at STM32F030K6 - It also has 32 pins, RTC, internal clock, but much cheaper (~2$), has easy to use configuration utility - stm32 CubeMX(+cubeF0), you can programm it with serial port.